# Using algebra to solve the number of different designs can a handkerchief with 16 squares have?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

Supposed we have a handkerchief of size 4x4 = 16 squares.

How many different designs of handkerchiefs can we obtain using 4 different colours.

I think it is just 4^16 since every square can be filled with one of the 4 colours. However this question is worth 10 marks in my assignment. So I am wondering if it is really that simple? I categorize this under abstract algebra because it is one of the question in my algebra course so maybe I have to use some algebra method to solve it but I am not really sure.

Comment: [Note] It will have rotational and other symmetries so some of the patterns in the $4^{16}$ will be repeated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the point of this question is that you can rotate or flip over the handkerchief, so you have a group action acting on the set of $4^{16}$ possibilities and you want to know how many distinct orbits there are under the group action.

Comment: i have not learnt group actions and orbits

Comment: I believe that really is the right "algebra" way to look at the problem so I'm not sure why your teacher gave it to you then if you haven't learned about group actions yet.

Answer (score 0):

If the northwest four and southeast four are red, and the the northeast four and southwest four are blue, that is the same pattern as if you swapped red and blue, because you could rotate the first pattern to get the second.
For most patterns, you get seven other patterns by rotating and flipping the hanky.  For this pattern I mentioned, you only get the two in total.
Count how many give you eight patterns by rotating and flipping; how many give you four; how many give two; how many give one.